# not getting output of traversal method after calling missing the numeric outputs at last

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I have called the two traversal method from in the main class but none of them showing any output
code :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        BinarySearchTree newBST = new BinarySearchTree();
        
        newBST.insert(70);
        newBST.insert(50);
        newBST.insert(90);
        newBST.insert(30);
        newBST.insert(60);
        newBST.insert(80);
        newBST.insert(100);
        newBST.insert(20);
        newBST.insert(40);  
        
        newBST.preOrder(newBST.root);
        newBST.inOrder(newBST.root);
        

    }

}
public class BinaryNode {
    
    public int value;
    public int height;
    //child
    public BinaryNode left;
    public BinaryNode right;
    

}

public class BinarySearchTree {
    
    BinaryNode root;
    
    public BinarySearchTree() {
        root = null; 
        
    }
    
    // Insert Method
    private BinaryNode insert(BinaryNode currentNode, int value) {
        
        if(currentNode == null) { 
            BinaryNode newNode = new BinaryNode(); 
            newNode.value = value; 
            System.out.println("The value successfully inserted"); 
            return newNode;
        } else if(value <= currentNode.value){ 
            currentNode.left = insert(currentNode.left, value); 
            return currentNode; 
        } else {
            currentNode.right = insert(currentNode.right, value);
            return currentNode; 
        }
    
    }
    
    public void insert(int value) {
        insert(root, value);
    }
    
    // Pre Order Traversal 
    public void preOrder(BinaryNode node) {
        if(node == null) {
            return;
        }
        System.out.print(node.value + " ");
        preOrder(node.left);
        preOrder(node.right);   
        
    }
    
    //In Order traversal
    public void inOrder(BinaryNode node) {
        if(node == null) {
            System.out.println("ACV");
            return;
        }
        
        inOrder(node.left);
        System.out.print(node.value + " ");
        inOrder(node.right);
    }

}
```

expected output :

```
Successfullyinserted 9 times
70 50 30 20 40 60 90 80 100
20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
```

I am just getting the output like

```
The value successfully inserted
The value successfully inserted
The value successfully inserted
The value successfully inserted
The value successfully inserted
The value successfully inserted
The value successfully inserted
The value successfully inserted
The value successfully inserted
ACV
```

Answer (score 0):

You never set `root` when inserting, therefore your tree is empty and remains empty and there is nothing you can print.

In your recursive `insert(BinaryNode currentNode, int value)` method you create a new node which is a local variable and you return that value. But you don't use that return value hence the newly created object is not referenced from anywhere and it will therefore be garbage collected.

Adjust your `insert(int value)` method to use `root = insert(root, value)` and it will work as you expect it to.

```java
public void insert(int value) {
    this.root = insert(root, value);
}
```

Comment: thanks@Mushroomator. Yes thanks its working after setting root = insert(root, value)